# What's the name of this font?

Tags: support, design

I came across this site accidentally and noticed the font in this site:
[image]
Would anyone(mods?) care to tell me what this font is?
I do not know wether this is the right place to ask this silly question , but I feel like I am right because this question is related to [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), so I am asking here.

Answer (score 5):

Viewing the source reports it to be [Pf Tempesta Seven Regular](http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/PF-Tempesta-Seven-Regular).

[image]

Comment: "a member of the sans-serif family." That's not how `font-family` works. `sans-serif` is the fallback font if the font didn't exist, or in this case, the font didn't load. *Sans-serif* itself is merely your browser's default sans font - [the term means 'without serif'.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans_serif)

Comment: That css line doesn't say that Pf Tempesta Seven Regular is a sans-serif font. That just says to use a sans-serif font if the browser can't/doesn't want to handle the previously named font. It *is* a sans-serif font though (as it has no serifs)

Comment: While it is true the font-family line does not work that way. Tempesta **is** a member of the san-serif family. Which is readily apparent to anyone looking at it.

Comment: I think you guys are all just mis-interpreting my definition of font family. I use the term loosely.. as in a group of fonts that are sans serif :P I never actually say that the browser reports it to be sans serif, @Arperum, simply that it is a sans serif fontface.